# How to find the MVC version of a .NET Visual Studio project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

We are documenting the app, so we found the NET Version but we couldn't find the MVC version of the project. I need to know how to find it.

I tried with properties of the project but I found the Target Framework: NET 6, and I couldn't find the MVC version this project is using.

Comment: In the Solution Explorer, under your project expand `References` / `System.Web.Mvc`, right click -> properties -> version. But the location may be different depending on VS and .Net versions.

Answer (score 0):

Open Web.config file and find the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly:

```
assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0 ..."
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below:

**Method One:**

1. Expand Reference in Solution Explorer and find System.Web.Mvc
2. Right-click System.Web.Mvc and click Properties to display the mvc version in Version

[image]

[image]

**Method Two:**

1. Use Notepad to open the csproj file of the asp.net project

[image]

2. Find System.Web.Mvc to view the mvc version

[image]